# Book about a human with black hair and a blue sword, and a blue/green striped alien

Tags: story-identification

I've had this book on my mind for a while. I remember very little of reading it, if I read any of it at all, but I would like to find out the name of it so that I can track down a copy to read.

I remember a science-fiction/fantasy book for the 80's or 90's with a mustard-orange book cover. On the front is a depiction of some of the main characters. I remember there being multiple characters on the front, but I only remember two of them. One was a human who had black hair and a blue sword. The other character that I can remember was some sort of a blue and green striped alien that I remember thinking looked like a Hershey's Kiss. The background of the illustration is a forest and the characters seem to be strolling through it.

As far as the contents of the book go, I remember there being some kind of a stone building on the planet that they were on.

Comment: I have to ask, if you don't remember any more about the contents, why are you interested in tracking down the book?

Comment: I was thinking that I may like to actually read it all the way through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be "[The End of the Matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_the_Matter)" by Alan Dean Foster.

It has a blue/green striped alien and a forest. No sword though.

[image]

Comment: My memory had bent and twisted the image so that the gun looked like a sword, but this is the one. Thank you.

Comment: I always thought Flinx (Phillip Lynx) was one of ADF's most interesting character creations ever.